# not able to call the class in c# visual studio

Tags: c#, wpf

I have many classes in my program and I'm using Visual Studio 2019 c# WPF, but now I want to call class B(class b has a node structure which I need in class A) in class A which am not able to do.
Please help me find a solution.

the error am getting in class A is for I3CHostInterface(3rd line)
I3CHostInterface is the name of class B.

class B:

```
 public static NodeStructure[] GetDeviceList(eNodeType nodeType)
 {
     return DeviceConfiguration.GetNodeList(nodeType);
 }
```

class A :

```
var traceDevice = new TraceConfigurations();
traceDevice.NodeList = new List<NodeStructure>();           


traceDevice.NodeList.AddRange(I3CHostInterface.GetDeviceList(eNodeType.Master));
```

Comment: Are both classes in the same assembly? Is class B declared internal/public?

Comment: avoid using the I prefix for Class Names. Use it for Interfaces only..

Comment: @AkshayGaonkar probably I in I3C is not a prefix (alhough a type that doesn't start with capital letter is not really standard); FalyDsouza having described what the actual error is would be useful :|

Comment: In order to avoid confusion (as in the comments above), do not name classes A and B if they have real names. Say "class I3CHostInterface" instead of "class B".

Comment: thank you all for the answers! i could get rid of the error by creating an instance of I3CHostInterface but now the values are not passing from I3CHostInterface.

Answer (score -2):

I think you are calling a method from an interface (naming would suggest that) and that has no implementation.

If you resolved the instance of the class (using dependency injection for example) call the actual object not the type.

Edit your question and show how the B class is implemented. That would provide more info.

Comment: yes i created instance of the class and was able to call it.